# Skew text in scribus

Tags: text, transform, scribus, skew

Is there a way to skew text in Scribus?

I know there is `Item > Transform > Transform > Skewing`, but this only skews the text frame, not the actual text within it.

Another idea is to transform the text to a path first, but i want to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow, I have the feeling that applying transformations to a font is not a good habit in the print business...

In my opinion, print shops that require the whole text to be outlined are overreacting, but it shows how sensitive the whole process is...

From a quick internet search, I had the feeling that the other well known DTP tool, also does not allow either to skew text.

The solution is really to duplicate the text, convert it to path and apply the transformation to it (and keep the original text on an non-printing layer or outside of the page).